# Redirecting to an external website from django view

Tags: django

Is there a way to redirect to another website from inside a Django view? I tried `return redirect("www.google.com")`, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `return redirect("https://google.com/")` , should work...

**Edit:**
I spend some time to figure out why this happens. I'm still not sure, but... `redirect` return result of call to `HttpResponseRedirect` with argument from call to `resolve_url()`. I've tried to call it with both:
`resolve_url("https://google.com/")` and `resolve_url("www.google.com")`, both output url strings `"https://google.com/"` and `"www.google.com"`. Next, this url passed to `urlparse(force_text(url))` and compared against `allowed_schemes = ['http', 'https', 'ftp']`. I've tried to fetch both url to `urlparse`, here is output:

```
for https://google.com/:
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='google.com', path='/', params='', query='', fragment='')

for www.google.com:
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='www.google.com', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Hope it helps!